# Magento 2.3.5 create boolean custom Customer Attribute

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, customer

I am trying to create a Yes/No attribute for Customer in the admin panel, but its not working. I have tried several available solutions but didn't seem to work. My code is given below.

`/Setup/InstallData.php`

> ```
> class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface {
> protected $customerSetupFactory;
>
> private $eavSetupFactory;
> private $eavConfig;
> private $attributeResource;
>
> public function __construct(
>     CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
>     EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory,
>     Config $eavConfig,
>     \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Attribute $attributeResource
> )
> {
>     $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
>     $this->eavConfig = $eavConfig;
>     $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
>     $this->attributeResource = $attributeResource;
> }
>
> public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
> {
>     $setup->startSetup();
>
>     /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
>     $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
>
>     $customerSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
>     'random_customer', [
>         'type' => 'int',
>         'label' => 'Attribute Approved',
>         'input' => 'select',
>         'source' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean',
>         'default' => '0',
>         'required' => false,
>         'visible' => true,
>         'user_defined' => true,
>         'system' => 0,
>         'position' => 999,
>         'is_used_in_grid' => true,
>         'is_visible_in_grid' => true,
>     ]);
>
>     $myAttribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
>  'random_customer');
>
>     $myAttribute->setData('used_in_forms', ['adminhtml_customer']);
>
>     $this->attributeResource->save($myAttribute);
>
>     $setup->endSetup();
> } }
> ```

I upgraded and regenerated code & static files but I do not see the option. However, if I try to add the text attribute, it works fine. But I am trying to create Boolean (Yes/No) attribute.

Comment: this might be useful to you https://blog.gaiterjones.com/magento-2-custom-customer-registration-checkbox-and-text-attributes/

Answer (score 0):

Try Below Code.

```
<?php

use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Set as AttributeSet;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    protected $customerSetupFactory;

    private $attributeSetFactory;

    public function __construct(
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
        AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
    ) {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
        $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
    }   
      
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
          
        $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
        $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

        $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);
          
        $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'approve_account', [
            'type' => 'int',
            'label' => 'Approve Account',
            'input' => 'select',
            'source' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean',
            'required' => false,
            'visible' => true,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'position' => 1,
            'system' => 0,
            'is_used_in_grid'       => true,
            'is_visible_in_grid'    => true,

        ]);
          
        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'approve_account')
        ->addData([
            'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
            'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
            'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer', 'customer_account_create', 'customer_account_edit'],//you can use other forms also
        ]);
          
        $attribute->save();
    }
}
```

**`THANKS.`**

Comment: I tried, but didn't work. I even disabled the module and re-enabled it. I have magento 2.3.5 installed

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below code snippet. It will display a boolean switch for Yes/No values.

```
$this->customerSetup->addAttribute(
    Customer::ENTITY,
    'attribute_approved',
    [
        'label' => 'Attribute approved',
        'required' => 0,
        'type' => 'int',
        'input' => 'boolean',
        'system' => 0,
        'user_defined' => 1,
    ]
);
```