# Cron job that delete customer in database

Tags: magento2, module, crontab, delete

below is the cron job code that suppose to delete customer if they have value of 1 in deleteOrders field but it not doing that, what am i missing?

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\ThreeYearOrders\Cron;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;

class DeleteOrder
{
    /**
     * @var Session
     */
    protected $_customerSession;
    
    /**
     * @param Session $customerSession
     */
    public function __construct(Session $customerSession)
    {
        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $customerId = $this->_customerSession->getCustomerId();

        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $resource = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
        $log = $objectManager->get('\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface');

        $connection = $resource->getConnection();
        $tableName = $connection->getTableName('customer_entity');

        try {
            $where = [
                'entity_id = ?' => $customerId,
                'deleteOrders = ?' => 1
            ];
            $connection->delete($tableName, $where);
            $log->info('Customer is deleted');
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $log->error("Error deleting customer: " . $e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

This is crontab.xml file below that execute and run cronjob file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
    <group id="default">
        <job name="Vendor_threeyearorders_delete_orders" instance="Vendor\ThreeYearOrders\Cron\DeleteOrder" method="execute">
            <schedule>* * * * *</schedule>
        </job>
    </group>
</config>
```

Setup file

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\ThreeYearOrders\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;

class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{
    public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();

        $table = $installer->getTable('customer_entity');

        $installer->getConnection()->addColumn(
            $table,
            'deleteOrders',
            [
                'type' => Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                'nullable' => true,
                'default' => null,
                'comment' => 'Delete Orders'
            ]
        );

        $installer->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Comment: iS deleteOrders field exist at customer_entity table?

Comment: yes it exist and i have added installschema on my post above @AmitBera

Comment: You have created deleteOrders fields in the wrong way created. You have to  create this 
 field using eav https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/88245/magento-2-how-to-create-a-customer-custom-attribute,then  https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/367145/4564 will work properly if create deleteOrders as attribute

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/334688/magento-2-3-5-create-boolean-custom-customer-attribute

Answer (score 2):

Try all steps it will be useful for you

1.Create the registration file on path
`app/code/Vendor/ThreeYearOrders/registration.php`

```
 <?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_ThreeYearOrders',
    __DIR__
);
```

2.Define the module's module.xml file on path `app/code/Vendor/ThreeYearOrders/etc/module.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_ThreeYearOrders" setup_version="1.0.0" />
</config>
```

3.Create the cron job class at
`app/code/Vendor/ThreeYearOrders/Cron/DeleteOrder.php`

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\ThreeYearOrders\Cron;

use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class DeleteOrder
{
    /**
     * @var CustomerRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $customerRepository;

    /**
     * @var LoggerInterface
     */
    protected $logger;

    /**
     * @param CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository
     * @param LoggerInterface $logger
     */
    public function __construct(
        CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
        LoggerInterface $logger
    ) {
        $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        try {
            $customersToDelete = $this->customerRepository->getList(
                $this->customerRepository->getSearchCriteria()
                    ->addFilter('deleteOrders', 1)
            );

            foreach ($customersToDelete->getItems() as $customer) {
                $this->customerRepository->delete($customer);
                $this->logger->info('Customer with ID ' . $customer->getId() . ' has been deleted.');
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->error("Error deleting customers: " . $e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

4.Create the cron job configuration file at `app/code/Vendor/ThreeYearOrders/etc/crontab.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
    <group id="default">
        <job name="vendor_threeyearorders_delete_orders" instance="Vendor\ThreeYearOrders\Cron\DeleteOrder" method="execute">
            <schedule>* * * * *</schedule>
        </job>
    </group>
</config>
```

5.Run the setup:upgrade command

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

After creating the necessary files, run the following command from the Magento root directory to apply the database changes and register the module

Answer (score 0):

Update your `DeleteOrder.php` with below code and run
**php bin/magento s:d:c**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\ThreeYearOrders\Cron;

use Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;

class DeleteOrder
{
    /**
     * @var customerFactory
     */
    protected $customerFactory;

    /**
     * @var registry
     */
    protected $registry;
    
    /**
     * @param CustomerFactory $customerFactory
     * @param Registry $registry
     */
    public function __construct(
        CustomerFactory $customerFactory,
        Registry $registry
    ) {
        $this->customerFactory = $customerFactory;
        $this->registry = $registry;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $this->registry->register('isSecureArea', true);
        $customerCollection = $this->customerFactory->create()->getCollection()
                        ->addFieldToFilter("deleteOrders", 1)
                        ->load();

        if ($customerCollection && count($customerCollection) > 0) {
            foreach ($customerCollection as $customer) {
                    $id = $customer->getId();
                    $customer = $this->customerFactory->create()->load($id);
                    $customer->delete();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of $customerCollection you meant $collection? or it right like this?

Comment: @Bayzel yup right, I have updated it. Please let me know if you face any issue